# How to add '$' symbol in TextInput when user enter any value in react-native

Tags: react-native

[image: it's sample what I actual need]

when I entered any number value in textInput then automatically '$' symbol is generating

```
<TextInput 
              style={styles.touchmodelstyle}
              autoFocus={true}
              keyboardType='number-pad'
              >
</TextInput>
```

Comment: Add your code to get through the issue.

Comment: you want to add $ or you want to get rescued from that auto entering $, Heading and description are confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Its a little tricky but does the job

```
<TextInput
    value={this.state.value}
    onChangeText={(text) => {
        text = text.split('$').join('')
        this.setState({
            value: `${text}$`
        })
    }
}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for solving my issue

Comment: What's final result should be?

Comment: value can not remove entered value ?

Comment: this way you can't delete characters, because every time you change the value you will append $ to the end of the text

Answer (score 0):

I found my question answer so I want to post it.

```
handleDollar = (value) => {
        this.setState({ dollar: value })
    };

    <View style={styles.touchmodelstyle}>
                                    <Text style={{ marginLeft: RFValue(60), 
                                                   marginVertical: RFValue(20), 
                                                   width: wp('4%'), 
                                                   height: hp('5%'), 
                                                   elevation: 1 }}>
                                  {this.state.dollar === "" ? "" : "$"}</Text>
                                    <TextInput
                                        autoFocus={true}
                                        placeholder={"other Amount"}
                                        keyboardType='number-pad'
                                        maxLength={3}
                                        value={this.state.dollar}
                                        onChangeText={(value) => this.handleDollar(value)}
                                    >
                                    </TextInput>
   </View>
```